# IMDb's redirect hyperlink not working after scraping using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the data of official sites of a title page on IMDb using Beautiful Soup.
For example, if I need to get data of [Intersteller](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0816692/), I have this code:

```py
url = 'https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0816692/'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
title_detail_soup = soup.find('div', {'id': 'titleDetails'})
details_soup = title_detail_soup.find_all('div', class_='txt-block')
detail_list = ['Official Sites:', 'Country:', 'Language:',
                'Release Date:', 'Also Known As:', 'Filming Locations:']
details = {}
for detail in details_soup:
    try:
        # Each heading (h4) has detail heading
        head = detail.find('h4')
        if head.get_text() in detail_list:
            # If the detail heading is in the detail list
            if head.get_text() == 'Official Sites:':
                # If details is about official sites
                official_site = {}
                detail.h4.decompose()    # remove <h4> tags
                a_tags = detail.find_all('a')
                for a_tag in a_tags:
                    # exclude See more>> links
                    if a_tag.get_text() != 'See more':
                        data = url+a_tag['href']    # final link is base URL + hyperlink
                        official_site[a_tag.get_text()] = data
                details['official-sites'] = official_site
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
print(details)    # Print the detail dictionary
```

HTML of the page:

```html
<div class="article" id="titleDetails">
    <span class="rightcornerlink">
        <a href="https://contribute.imdb.com/updates?edit=tt0816692/details&amp;ref_=tt_dt_dt">Edit</a>
    </span>
    <h2>Details</h2>
    <div class="txt-block">
        <h4 class="inline">Official Sites:</h4>
            <a href="/offsite/?page-action=offsite-facebook&amp;token=BCYpckvEa_ZSPp2TC3Ztr1DNqde5ZCUHig7950CLYvsgSHOzBCfJSHpgg71IYRsZYP1DuUpTZb9H%0D%0AhK4BzY5AiKU5Vy2oFn7i91MVFT_TnR39yhU5V5NBAse2mY_ht5WdsmSBxQPGRBC6pIJJym7IXbao%0D%0ATz9SG3r8MjKfwIe9hBrJU5Y-vNdnR_uaDq_24s2NGj5ikJYWl_093YIHy_I2lnK-I6jK9OvOpwgw%0D%0AupABQOymuxA%0D%0A&amp;ref_=tt_pdt_ofs_offsite_0" rel="nofollow">Official Facebook</a>
        <span class="ghost">|</span>
            <a href="/offsite/?page-action=offsite-interstellarmovie&amp;token=BCYuB9Ouy5QXl_3W_k3RrnnXUdrfSLbBFfOcrJTX0yo5TtTDqsSLpry8x7drK8l0xpOJSEqt73Hz%0D%0A08qyki3_i83CrCym7SXSkevFQpT32TjuuJLgIlQ-W5CpRd-wZC9eD4R3SZOMdOfSjeoOtqiE5uU_%0D%0Az-YG1i5AImXY2xLmHSNwABh1hU7VHS-FnqKDW9G-4KOF78zpKdDIfrwlRs8px0yef9u51LojZz05%0D%0A0OBfTmRs_JI%0D%0A&amp;ref_=tt_pdt_ofs_offsite_1" rel="nofollow">Official site</a>
        <span class="ghost">|</span>
        <span class="see-more inline">
            <a href="externalsites?ref_=tt_dt_dt#official">See more</a>&nbsp;»
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have successfully extracted data into a dictionary format using this but when I use the hyperlinks from the dictionary, they **don't work and gives out error for requested URL not found.**

Output dictionary:

```py
{
    'official-sites': {
        'Official Facebook': 'https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0816692/offsite/?page-action=offsite-facebook&token=BCYqzjQrP9OA_yaYNwA9Q8hI5gt41EmHuu0_ePjZPHKui-hEmAEySo-0SHzZmSjpeeEVy3Art6SH%0D%0ATseW16b3uKMjIH8iOyO-ZVYR025mQ4YCbZIWUKEcEM-z0eOeUvud3KGbuQTCxrNhTGAx7xgFIB89%0D%0Al9jT6pvqSpSCdNYACnBhk_8MuNjCn8GIJZk-6PR1MZ1xQB5yDrqRNhNt9Dg8IDMXVpxTR8-LFu2I%0D%0Amf5KmXbmXos%0D%0A', 
        'Official site': 'https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0816692/offsite/?page-action=offsite-interstellarmovie&token=BCYsMb9WTKJLH9M9nmxvLDpn8ikQDnQmpVQZBurp9Trd1-XXbA_Bh4xoKx6yf3Qx4YNn3fT9UhFe%0D%0AnzcULcEY5SFJ7CW8kBj6dQvZA9GyvqfZMyIDS7daNe6rne6DkdL23CDPAkk1Xwr9rjiE6FF_m0vX%0D%0ASLH2NnzOf8BcKnaWILhGGdvHTYeZ_uRGm4QCIOzxw-CvLM2rag04ZbXM2ZUEvQm6OedW9XumtsnQ%0D%0AoP7ce67sytE%0D%0A'
    }
}
```

Comment: I copied the URL from the page on IMDb and entered in another window. It worked as expected. But, I noticed one thing that the token in the URL actually changes every time the page is refreshed!

Answer (score 0):

for all code where you call get_text(), please make sure objects is not empty,

try using this:

```
url = 'https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0816692/'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
title_detail_soup = soup.find('div', {'id': 'titleDetails'})
headings_soup = title_detail_soup.find_all(['h2', 'h3'])
details_soup = title_detail_soup.find_all('div', class_='txt-block')
detail_list = ['Official Sites:', 'Country:', 'Language:',
                'Release Date:', 'Also Known As:', 'Filming Locations:']
details = {}
for detail in details_soup:
    try:
        head = detail.find('h4')
        if head.get_text() in detail_list:
            if head.get_text() == 'Official Sites:':
                official_site = {}
                detail.h4.decompose()
                a_tags = detail.find_all('a')
                for a_tag in a_tags:
                    if a_tag.get_text() != 'See more':
                        data = url +a_tag['href']
                        official_site[a_tag.text] = data
                details['official-sites'] = official_site
    except Exception as e:
        # print(e)
        pass
print(details)
```

Comment: I tried using your code. But it shows the same error. I have added new output and other things. Maybe it can help you get the issue.

Comment: cause you get not real url but protect with token

Comment: Well, that's how it is on the page on the title. I have copied the URL from the page as well and it works. I noticed another thing that the token actually changes every time the page refreshes.